# NSDate (Time Elapsed) to Hours

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to calculate the average speed of the user using Core Location, so I have a total distance traveled in miles (`double totalDistance`) and the time elapsed (`NSDate *timeElapsed`).

How can I convert `timeElapsed` to a double displaying hours? I.e. 0.1 hours, 0.0001 hours, etc so that I can calculate my average speed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the date object into a `NSTimeInterval` (with `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` or `timeIntervalSinceDate:` if you have a different start date), then divide the `NSTimeInterval` by 3600.

Comment: I did this but my output is completely wrong. Travelling at 70mph (around there), `totalDistance/(timeElapsedInterval/3600)` is coming out incorrectly; totalDistance is miles, timeElapsedInterval is in seconds. I feel like I'm skipping something very obvious.

Comment: `averageSpeed = totalDistance/timeElapsedInterval*3600` seemed to fix it.

Comment: You do realize that `a/(b/c)` is equal to `a/b*c`, right? Both are not equal to `a/b/c`.

Comment: Right, but in the code the first way I was doing it was coming out 0.000000000000001293 (or something similar). I'm not sure if the parenthesis were working correctly, or what was going on, hence why I was so puzzled.